# How do you generate a CSR in Java without signing it by the requester?

Tags: java, certificate, asn.1, csr

Basically, I need to isolate the data of the constructed CSR (Certificate Signing Request) prior to it being first signed by the entity making the request, preferably in Java. Many thanks in advance!

It would also be useful to note how to subsequently append the signature to the CSR as the CSR data will be initially signed by an HSM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;


import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

import sun.security.pkcs10.*;
import sun.security.x509.*;

public class GenerateCSR {
    private static PublicKey publicKey = null;
    private static PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    private static KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
    private static GenerateCSR gcsr = null;

    private GenerateCSR() {
        try {
            keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        keyGen.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair keypair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        publicKey = keypair.getPublic();
        privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();
    }

    public static GenerateCSR getInstance() {
        if (gcsr == null)
            gcsr = new GenerateCSR();
        return gcsr;
    }

    public String getCSR(String cn) throws Exception {
        byte[] csr = generatePKCS10(cn, "Java", "JournalDev", "Cupertino",
                "California", "USA");
        return new String(csr);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param CN
     *            Common Name, is X.509 speak for the name that distinguishes
     *            the Certificate best, and ties it to your Organization
     * @param OU
     *            Organizational unit
     * @param O
     *            Organization NAME
     * @param L
     *            Location
     * @param S
     *            State
     * @param C
     *            Country
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static byte[] generatePKCS10(String CN, String OU, String O,
            String L, String S, String C) throws Exception {
        // generate PKCS10 certificate request
        String sigAlg = "MD5WithRSA";
        PKCS10 pkcs10 = new PKCS10(publicKey);
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(sigAlg);
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        // common, orgUnit, org, locality, state, country
        X500Principal principal = new X500Principal( "CN=Ole Nordmann, OU=ACME, O=Sales, C=NO");

   //     pkcs10CertificationRequest kpGen = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(sigAlg, principal, publicKey, null, privateKey);  
     //   byte[] c = kpGen.getEncoded();  
        X500Name x500name=null;
        x500name= new X500Name(principal.getEncoded());
      pkcs10.encodeAndSign(x500name, signature);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(bs);
        pkcs10.print(ps);
        byte[] c = bs.toByteArray();
        try {
            if (ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if (bs != null)
                bs.close();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
        }
        return c;
    }

    public PublicKey getPublicKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }

    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
        return privateKey;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GenerateCSR gcsr = GenerateCSR.getInstance();

        System.out.println("Public Key:\n"+gcsr.getPublicKey().toString());

        System.out.println("Private Key:\n"+gcsr.getPrivateKey().toString());
        String csr = gcsr.getCSR("journaldev.com <http://www.journaldev.com>");
        System.out.println("CSR Request Generated!!");
        System.out.println(csr);
    }

}
```

Comment: Accepting your answer since you were able to provide a code example. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this work has been repeated almost verbatim here: http://www.journaldev.com/223/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-using-java-api

Comment: Please do due diligence before you accuse someone of copying stuffs. My post is from 2011 and it's copied from there to here. You can check yourself in wayback machine. https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.journaldev.com/223/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-using-java-api

Comment: well, I have used material from journaldev  and I kept signature from journaldev to make this clear( plz see the bottom lines) . anyway I did not copy pasted as it was part of a real world development, just salt-pepper on it to make it generic.

Comment: I tried this code, it works fine thanks a lot, but sonar is giving error as "Remove this use of constructor" for your code "new PrintStream(bs);". Please help me out, any alternative is there?

Comment: @SurendraKumarJaiswal , Sorry this is a 7 years old code and is quite messy, actually I think your sonar qube is right in this case as ps is not used to generate output. you can use ps to generate a log or  just remove ps and all its references in code and write directly into bs or  just use another type of stream.

Comment: Using the internal `sun.security.*` classes is long since been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Bouncy Castle libraries to produce a certificate request without signing it. The problem I was facing was that a lot of applications available to generate a CSR took care of both generating it AND signing it. I only wanted to produce an unsigned CSR. Unfortunately, I cannot divulge the code used to produce the unsigned CSR due to company policy but I have listed many hints below that should help others. Here are some steps that might aid someone else trying to do the same thing:

1. Look at example CSR data generated with openssl or some other tool using the following website.

   http://lapo.it/asn1js/

   This site even includes an example certificate object to see it in action.
2. Become familiar with ASN1 encoding. This is how certificate data is encoded and you will need to encode the CSR similarly using Bouncy Castle.
3. Use Bouncy Castle to produce the CSR data. Here is a code snippet on initializing some of the fields typically found in CSR data.

   ```
   // Create Organization Name<br/>
   DERObjectIdentifier oidOrgName     = new DERObjectIdentifier("2.5.4.10");
   DERPrintableString  prntstrOrgName = new DERPrintableString("Test Organization");
   DERSet              setOrgName     = new DERSet(new DERSequence(new ASN1Encodable[] {oidOrgName, prntstrOrgName}));

   // Create org unit name
   DERObjectIdentifier oidOrgUnitName     = new DERObjectIdentifier(2.5.4.11);
   DERPrintableString  prntstrOrgUnitName = new DERPrintableString("Org Unit Name");
   DERSet              setOrgUnitName     = new DERSet(new DERSequence(new ASN1Encodable[] {oidOrgUnitName, prntstrOrgUnitName}));
   ```

Comment: Your example can be replaced with `new X500Name("O=Test Organisation, OU=Org Unit Name")`